# GDB Debugger: An internal issue to GDB has been detected

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, nasm, x86-64

I'm new to GNU Debugger. I've been playing around with it, debugging Assembly Files (`x86_64 Linux`) for a day or so and just a few hours ago I ''discovered'' the TUI interface.

My first attempt using the TUI interface was to see the register changes as I execute each line at a time of a simple Hello World program (in asm). Here is the code of the program

```
section .data
        text db "Hello, World!", 10
        len equ $-text
section .text

        global _start

_start:

        nop

        call _printText

        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall

_printText:

        nop

        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, text
        mov rdx, len
        syscall
        ret
```

After creating the executable file in the terminal of linux I write

```
$ gdb -q ./hello -tui
```

Then I created three breakpoints: one right of the `_start`, another right after `_printText` and the last just above the `mov rax, 60` for the `SYS_EXIT`.

After this:

1) I run the program.

2) On gdb mode I write `layout asm` to see the written code.

3) I write `layout regs.`

4) Finally I use `stepi` to see how the register change according the the written hello world program.

The thing is that when the `RIP` register points to the address of `ret`, corresponding to `SYS_EXIT` and I hit `Enter` I get the following message in console

```
[Inferior 1 (process 2059) exited normally]
/build/gdb-cXfXJ3/gdb-7.11.1/gdb/thread.c:1100: internal-error: finish_thread_st
ate: Assertion `tp' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n)
```

If I type `n` It appears this (as it says, it quits if I type `y`):

```
This is a bug, please report it.  For instructions, see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

    /build/gdb-cXfXJ3/gdb-7.11.1/gdb/thread.c:1100: internal-error: finish_thread_st
    ate: Assertion `tp' failed.
    A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
    further debugging may prove unreliable.
    Create a core file of GDB? (y or n)
```

As I don't know what a core file of GDB (and what is useful for), so I type `n` and the debugging session closes.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how can be fixed?

By the way, I'm new in Assembly also, so if this occurs because of something wrong in the program I'd also appreciate if anyone can point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same GDB version as you and I always use the TUI features; but I've never had this problem. However, when I use your code the internal GDB error occurs.  But if I make one change in your write syscall function, the error does not manifest.

Although you are not calling another function from within a function, I generally create a stack frame by including at least the "push rbp", "mov rbp, rsp", and "leave" instructions in my x86-64 function calls.  This may be a band-aide or a work around with respect to the "bug".

```
_printText:
        push rbp
        mov rbp, rsp
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, text
        mov rdx, len
        syscall
        leave
        ret
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know why this is happening

It's happening because there is a bug in GDB (more precisely, an assertion that GDB internal variable `tp` is not `NULL` has been violated).

> and how can be fixed?

You should try to reproduce this with current version of GDB (the bug may have already been fixed), and file a bug report (like the message tells you).

> I don't know what a core file of GDB (and what is useful for),

It's only useful to GDB developers.

Comment: Probably this reported bug which was not fixed yet: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20176.

Comment: @ks1322 Probably a different bug: the bug here appears to show only with TUI, and is probably triggered by having ASM window after pogram terminates. I verified it's still present in trunk GDB from a few days ago: 8.0.50.20170429-git